# clearInterval not working in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have a variable refreshIntervalId declared in the constructor

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.init = false;
    a=this;
    this.refreshIntervalId;
}
```

I have a method onConsume which is called by another program. It has a setinterval which I need to clear every time it is called.

```
onConsume(requests) {
if (this.init) {
           console.log("clearing interval");
                   if(a.refreshIntervalId == null){
                      console.log("but refreshIntervalId  is null");
                   }else{
                      clearInterval(a.refreshIntervalId);
                    }
    }
     this.init = true;

            a.refreshIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
             ...}, 1000);
}
```

The first time setinterval is executed and it runs periodically. The 2nd time onConsume is called, "clearing interval" and "but refreshIntervalId  is null" is printed, and I can see 2 setintervals being executed.

Would anybody know why the refreshIntervalId is null. I have tried dfferent combinations of using this.refreshIntervalId  or just refreshIntervalId  itself, but nothing works.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you assigning `this` to a global variable? If you have multiple instances it will not work correctly, use `this` directly.

Comment: I tried this.refreshIntervalId too and it gives the same result

Answer (score 0):

Is onConsume a method on the same object with the constructor that you pasted at the top? If so you are referencing it as a.refreshIntervalId instead of this.refreshIntervalId. If not then I would make sure that 'a' is referencing the correct instance of the object with the interval on it. Also, remember

```
undefined == null; // returns true
undefined === null; // returns false
```

Comment: a is assigned to this. I tried this.refreshIntervalId too and it gives the same result

Comment: Did you also try using this.refreshIntervalId both in the setInterval and in the clearInterval? Also to clarify, after calling onConsume the second time, the intended outcome is to clear the old interval and set a new one?